# How to set shortcut key for AnkhSVN commit in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ankhsvn

I want to set a shortcut key to open the "Commit Solution Window", I just need to find out the command for it.

I am using AnkhSVN with Visual Studio 2010.

[image: screenshot]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `CommitPendingChanges` to do immediate commit.
- Use `File.CommitItem` to show "Commit to Subversion" dialog (the one where you can select items to commit and enter the log message).

For example, you can assign any of these commands to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and run commit using this keyboard shortcut.

Comment: This command directly commits the changes. I want the window to open where I can review the changes and put a commit message.

Comment: @Yasser I'm glad it helped. I'd upvote your question but I'm out of votes for today. Thanks for accepting my answer!